# Is it possible to update the PHP version of my web template to be up to date with my hosting service?

Tags: php, mail-form

my problem is that (to my understanding) the RD-Mailform.php and html code in my webpage for the RD-mailform are written with older versions of PHP, and therefore will not work with the server I am hosting my webpage on, which is version 7.3.20. Ultimately my goal is to simply have my contact forms on my webpage work.

I have tried swapping the entire mailform code in dreamweaver to see if I could at least get a different error message; same error. I have tried changing a small line of code (line 11) in the `rd-mailform.php`
from:
`$recipients = $formConfig['myemail@gmail.com'];`     (my personal email is filled out)
to:
`$recipients = 'myemail@gmail.com'`;
this changed my browser error from - MF001 (Recipients are not set!) to MF004 (Please, define type of your form!)

I do not understand how to define my form type. Please advise me on what I am overlooking and or if I am not understanding quite properly what the real issue is. (I can provide the mailform.json file code if necessary as well.

Here is the rd-mailform code I am looking at:

```
    <?php

$formConfigFile = file_get_contents("rd-mailform.config.json");
$formConfig = json_decode($formConfigFile, true);

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

try {
    require './phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $recipients = 'postersemail@mail.com';

    preg_match_all("/([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)/", $recipients, $addresses, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    if (!count($addresses[0])) {
        die('MF001');
    }

    function getRemoteIPAddress() {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

        } else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    if (preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.)/', getRemoteIPAddress())) {
        die('MF002');
    }

    $template = file_get_contents('rd-mailform.tpl');

    if (isset($_POST['form-type'])) {
        switch ($_POST['form-type']){
            case 'contact':
                $subject = 'A message from your site visitor';
                break;
            case 'subscribe':
                $subject = 'Subscribe request';
                break;
            case 'order':
                $subject = 'Order request';
                break;
            default:
                $subject = 'A message from your site visitor';
                break;
        }
    }else{
        die('MF004');
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $template = str_replace(
            array("<!-- #{FromState} -->", "<!-- #{FromEmail} -->"),
            array("Email:", $_POST['email']),
            $template);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
        $template = str_replace(
            array("<!-- #{MessageState} -->", "<!-- #{MessageDescription} -->"),
            array("Message:", $_POST['message']),
            $template);
    }

    preg_match("/(<!-- #\{BeginInfo\} -->)(.|\s)*?(<!-- #\{EndInfo\} -->)/", $template, $tmp, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != "counter" && $key != "email" && $key != "message" && $key != "form-type" && $key != "g-recaptcha-response" && !empty($value)){
            $info = str_replace(
                array("<!-- #{BeginInfo} -->", "<!-- #{InfoState} -->", "<!-- #{InfoDescription} -->"),
                array("", ucfirst($key) . ':', $value),
                $tmp[0][0]);

            $template = str_replace("<!-- #{EndInfo} -->", $info, $template);
        }
    }

    $template = str_replace(
        array("<!-- #{Subject} -->", "<!-- #{SiteName} -->"),
        array($subject, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']),
        $template);

    $mail = new PHPMailer();


    if ($formConfig['useSmtp']) {
        //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isSMTP();

        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (for production use)
        // 1 = client messages
        // 2 = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

        // Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host = $formConfig['host'];

        // Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
        $mail->Port = $formConfig['port'];

        // Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

        // Username to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = $formConfig['username'];

        // Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password = $formConfig['password'];
    }

    $mail->From = $addresses[0][0][0];

    # Attach file
    if (isset($_FILES['file']) &&
        $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
            $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['name'])){
        $mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
    }else{
        $mail->FromName = "Site Visitor";
    }

    foreach ($addresses[0] as $key => $value) {
        $mail->addAddress($value[0]);
    }

    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($template);
    $mail->send();

    die('MF000');
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    die('MF254');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('MF255');
}
```

HTML Code below, added 07/30/20 - 5:38 am

```
<!-- RD Mailform-->
          <form class="rd-form rd-mailform" data-form-output="form-output-global" data-form-type="contact" method="post" action="bat/rd-mailform.php">
            <div class="row row-20">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-icon input--nao">
                  <input class="form-input input__field--nao" id="contact-name" type="text" name="name" data-constraints="@Required">
                  <label class="form-label mdi mdi-account-outline input__label--nao" for="contact-name">Your Name</label>
                  <svg class="graphic graphic--nao" width="300%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1200 60" preserveaspectratio="none">
                    <path d="M0,56.5c0,0,298.666,0,399.333,0C448.336,56.5,513.994,46,597,46c77.327,0,135,10.5,200.999,10.5c95.996,0,402.001,0,402.001,0"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-icon input--nao">
                  <input class="form-input input__field--nao" id="contact-email" type="email" name="email" data-constraints="@Email @Required">
                  <label class="form-label input__label--nao mdi mdi-email-outline" for="contact-email">E-mail</label>
                  <svg class="graphic graphic--nao" width="300%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1200 60" preserveaspectratio="none">
                    <path d="M0,56.5c0,0,298.666,0,399.333,0C448.336,56.5,513.994,46,597,46c77.327,0,135,10.5,200.999,10.5c95.996,0,402.001,0,402.001,0"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-icon input--nao">
                  <input class="form-input input__field--nao" id="contact-phone" type="text" name="phone" data-constraints="@Numeric">
                  <label class="form-label input__label--nao mdi mdi-tablet-android" for="contact-phone">Phone</label>
                  <svg class="graphic graphic--nao" width="300%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1200 60" preserveaspectratio="none">
                    <path d="M0,56.5c0,0,298.666,0,399.333,0C448.336,56.5,513.994,46,597,46c77.327,0,135,10.5,200.999,10.5c95.996,0,402.001,0,402.001,0"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-icon input--nao">
                  <textarea class="form-input input__field--nao" id="contact-message" name="message" data-constraints="@Required"></textarea>
                  <label class="form-label input__label--nao mdi mdi-message-text-outline" for="contact-message">Your Message</label>
                  <svg class="graphic graphic--nao" width="300%" height="50%" viewbox="0 0 1200 60" preserveaspectratio="none">
                    <path d="M0,56.5c0,0,298.666,0,399.333,0C448.336,56.5,513.994,46,597,46c77.327,0,135,10.5,200.999,10.5c95.996,0,402.001,0,402.001,0"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 text-center form-button">
                <button class="button button-primary button-nina" type="submit">Send Message</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your form? Does it include a field called `form-type`?

Comment: I added the HTML to the bottom of my original post @fubar

Comment: and yes it does look like there is a field form-type

Comment: There's a data attribute for `form-type`, but there isn't a field defined within the HTML. I assume the value must be appended to the form or submission request dynamically with JavaScript. Have you checked the request content in the browser inspector? Are there any JS errors?

Comment: @fubar I checked for any errors as you mentioned, and yes I was at least guided to the script.js , where it still defined the same error, but it told me what line it was on.
Uncaught reference error: recipients is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> - script.js:1326
the line reads as: $recipients = 'myemail@mail.com';
that is it for the entire line.

Comment: I'm guessing that the JS error above is causing script to break before the `form-type` value is included in the page/request, which is causing your error. There's no recipients data included in the above HTML, so that might be a good starting point fot you to debug further.

Comment: @fubar Well I couldnt figure out what exactly was going wrong, so I opted to start my website with the original template from scratch again before any alterations were made to see if the code with the fresh template works out of the box. Anyway, I was able to get my site mailform working when using SMTP, but was not able to get it working without. I appreciate your help fubar, mystery still remains, but overall everything is working. Now i just need to make sure I tread carefully on my re-editing process. Cheers~